# How To Move Lightbox2 Close Buttons To Top

Tags: lightbox2

I would like to know how to move the close button in lightbox 2 to the top?

```
.lb-data .lb-close{display:block;
float:right;
width:30px;
height:30px;
background:url(../images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
text-align:right;
outline:0;
filter:alpha(Opacity=70);
opacity:.7;
-webkit-transition:opacity .2s;
-moz-transition:opacity .2s;
-o-transition:opacity .2s;transition:opacity .2s}
```

Answer (score 3):

add this code to your css:

```
.lb-data .lb-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```

you should play with the pixel sizes to locate it exactlly where you want.

Comment: I'm using lightbox 2.8.2 and your answer sent me in the right direction, thank you.  I had to add top:-35px and margin-left:-30px to .lb-data .lb-close, and then set .lb-data .lb-details to be 100% width to make my close button float where I wanted.  Thank you for the help!